# Finding a single "o" in loc from department table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
------- -------------- ---------
     10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
     20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
     30 SALES          CHICAGO
     40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

I want only CHICAGO and NEW YORK NOT BOSTON (only single `o`) in location. If I do:

```
select * 
from dept 
where loc like '%o%';
```

it will show more than one 'O' but i want only one.

Answer (score 4):

use `REGEXP_COUNT`

```
select * from department where  REGEXP_COUNT(loc,'o',1,'i') = 1; --'i' for case-insensitive
```

or `LENGTH` ( along with `lower()/upper()` on top to make it case-insensitive )

```
select * from department where  length(loc) - length(replace(loc,'O')) = 1
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d7323d4a132008942614dc702732f5f)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LENGTH()` to do it

```
SELECT * FROM department WHERE  (LENGTH(loc) - LENGTH(REPLACE(UPPER(loc),'O'))) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In such case We can simply use `INSTR` to search the number of occurrence of the desired character/string then add `=0` in the `WHERE` condition to retrieve the data where second occurrence is not exist

```
SELECT DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC
FROM yourtable
WHERE INSTR(LOC, 'O', 1, 2) = 0
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
DEPTNO  DNAME       LOC
10      ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
20      RESEARCH    DALLAS
30      SALES       CHICAGO
```

If you want at least one `O` must exist in the string then replace `WHERE` condition with below line

```
WHERE INSTR(LOC, 'O', 1, 2) = 0 AND INSTR(LOC, 'O', 1, 1) > 0
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
DEPTNO  DNAME       LOC
10      ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
30      SALES       CHICAGO
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use two comparisons:

```
select * 
from dept 
where loc like '%o%' and loc not like '%o%o%';
```

Note that Oracle is generally case sensitive, so I would recommend:

```
select * 
from dept 
where lower(loc) like '%o%' and loc not like '%o%o%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select * from Dept where regexp_count(loc,'O')=1;
```

This will work